# Why my code did not get into my function

Tags: c#

This is my function:

```
IEnumerable<Packet> packets = splitPacket(packet, 2);

public static IEnumerable<Packet> splitPacket(Packet packet, int numberOfFragments)
{
    //
}
```

I am calling this function but for some reason my code did not get into my function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your function is an [*iterator function*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx), meaning that it contains `yield return;` statements.

Code in iterator functions is only executed as the result is iterated.
This is called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: seriously? you got that from what he posted?

Comment: @JonB It's actually a fairly common problem.

Comment: @JonB - I'm betting the function's return type was a big sign in that direction.

Comment: @user1860927: You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.